# Is it possible to bake physics parallel on multiple blender instances?

Tags: fluid-simulation, performance

*Example*

1. cpu with 8 cores
2. animation with 16 frames
3. one fluid physics domain

It takes **32 seconds** to bake the fluid physics cache frames 0 to 16

Can I decrease the baking time to **16 seconds** by baking frame 0-7 on one
instance and frame 8-16 on another?

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't work. To make calculation in 8-16 frames, you have to get the results of calculation 0-7 frames as input or, shall we say, starting point. To calculate frame 8 you should have the result of frame 7; to calculate frame 7 you should have frame 6 calculated and so on down to first frame.